# xsl: Sort Multiple attributes

Tags: xslt

I have the below data, where I have multiple attributes:
I need to sort either by Datetime or by Timezone in ascending order. 
If input contains different Datetime and same Timezone it should output ascending per Datetime. 
If input contains same Datetime and different Timezone it should output ascending per Timezone.

Current Logic:

```
    <xsl:sort select="@Datetime" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@Timezone" order="ascending"/>
```

SAMPLE 1st scenario - output is as expected:

```
<MSG>
<DOC>
<Parent>
<Input Id="1234567890" Srvce="RRR" Cd="D1" Datetime="2016-06-16 20:42:30"    Timezone="+02:00" EvtRmk="DUMMY 1">
</Input>
<Input Id="1234567890" Srvce="RRR" Cd="D1" Datetime="2016-06-15 20:43:15" Timezone="+04:00" EvtRmk="DUMMY 1">
</Input>
```

Current output:

```
    <Output>2016-06-15 20:43:15"</Output>
    <Output>2016-06-16 20:42:30</Output>
```

SAMPLE 2nd scenario - Different Timezone/Same Datetime; output not sorted per Timezone:

```
<MSG>
</DOC>
<Parent>
<Input Id="1234567890" Srvce="RRR" Cd="D1" Datetime="2016-06-15 20:42:30" Timezone="+04:00" EvtRmk="DUMMY 1">
</Input>
<Input Id="1234567890" Srvce="RRR" Cd="D1" Datetime="2016-06-15 20:43:15" Timezone="+00:00" EvtRmk="DUMMY 1">
</Input>
```

Current Output:

```
<Output>2016-06-15 20:42:30</Output>
<Output>2016-06-15 20:43:15</Output>
```

Expected output:

```
<Output>2016-06-15 20:43:15</Output>
<Output>2016-06-15 20:42:30</Output>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the result of the sort in absolute chronological order?  That is equivalent to converting everything to UTC first and sorting on the timestamp.

Comment: yes, you are correct it needs to be sorted in chronological order.

Comment: Your expectation is unfounded: if you sort by datetime first, then `2016-06-15 20:42:30` will always come before `2016-06-15 20:43:15`. Any secondary sort will be only applied within groups created by the first sort.

Comment: "*it needs to be sorted in chronological order.*" Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - using 1.0

Comment: @vic-rattlehead That's going to be some work. Which XSLT 1.0 processor, specifically (there might be some extension support)?

Comment: @vic-rattlehead Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 1.0**, you will have to do this in two passes: first, equalize the input dateTimes to a common base such as UTC, then sort the results by this value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <!-- first-pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="inputs">
        <xsl:for-each select="Input">
            <input>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="@Datetime" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="@Timezone" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </input>    
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($inputs)/input">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <Input>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            </Input>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>
    <xsl:param name="offset"/>

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="local-time" select="substring-after($dateTime, ' ')" />

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="hour" select="substring($local-time, 1, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring($local-time, 4, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring($local-time, 7)" />

    <xsl:variable name="offset-sign" select="1 - 2 * starts-with($offset, '-')" />
    <xsl:variable name="offset-hour" select="substring($offset, 2, 2) * $offset-sign" />
    <xsl:variable name="offset-minute" select="substring($offset, 5, 2) * $offset-sign" />

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="jd" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:value-of select="86400*$jd + 3600*$hour + 60*$minute + $second - 3600*$offset-hour - 60*$offset-minute" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<Parent>
    <Input Id="001" Datetime="2016-06-15 19:44:30" Timezone="-02:30"/>
    <Input Id="002" Datetime="2016-06-15 20:42:30" Timezone="+04:00"/>
    <Input Id="003" Datetime="2016-06-15 21:43:15" Timezone="+00:00"/>
</Parent>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
   <Input Id="002" Datetime="2016-06-15 20:42:30" Timezone="+04:00"/>
   <Input Id="003" Datetime="2016-06-15 21:43:15" Timezone="+00:00"/>
   <Input Id="001" Datetime="2016-06-15 19:44:30" Timezone="-02:30"/>
</Parent>
```